# Talib indicators not working on .resample()'d dataframes; returns all NaN's

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, ta-lib

To reproduce, download my 15 second SPY stock OHLCV dataset [from here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ddEIa8mFOoRGoHA_DUtwSoZVhnebm5Lc/view?usp=sharing), and place in the same folder as this script. Should have `Talib` and `pandas` installed. Running Python 3.7.9, Windows 10.

Talib indicators don't seem to work after a df is upsampled to a higher timeframe, even though the dataframe remains numeric. I'm trying to upsample this 15 second dataset to a 5 minute timeframe. I attempt to add a moving average both before and after the resampling, before works fine, after returns all NaN's. Any idea why? (Will be back online tomorrow to review answers)

```
from pandas import read_csv, to_numeric, to_datetime
import talib

# Import the 15 second dataframe
df = read_csv("./SPY_15_Second.csv")
df['time'] = to_datetime(df['time'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df = df.set_index('time')

# Apply an SMA now and it works
df['SMA1'] = talib.SMA(df['close'], timeperiod=15)
print("First DF")
print(df)

# Upsample it to 5 minute dataset
ohlc_dict = {                                                                                                             
    'open': 'first',                                                                                                    
    'high': 'max',                                                                                                       
    'low': 'min',                                                                                                        
    'close': 'last',                                                                                                    
    'volume': 'sum',
}

df = df.resample('5min', closed='left', label='left').apply(ohlc_dict).apply(to_numeric)
print("Upsampled DF")
print(df)

# Try to apply a second simple moving average after resampling, see nans
df['SMA2'] = talib.SMA(df['close'], timeperiod=15)
print("Problem DF")
print(df)

# Why entire column nan? Attempted to apply to_numeric. Something
# to do with the resample function.
```

Answer (score 0):

It works if you use the `.ohlc()` method on it, and not reassign it to a variable, so in other words, use this:

Change this:

```
df = df.resample('5min', closed='left', label='left').apply(ohlc_dict).apply(to_numeric)
```

...to this:

```
df.resample('5min', closed='left', label='left').ohlc()
```